# Can't set headers after they are sent. in NodeJS using HBS

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, handlebars.js, template-engine

I get the following error while trying to render my page

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Below is what I am trying to do

```
   res.render('information', {
                    name: rows[i].name,
                    boxId: rows[i].box
                });

         console.log(rows[i].name);
```

It prints out the right information in the console, so i know that this is correct, but getting that information render at `information` page is an issue

```
  {{#each items}}
      <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden"  value="{{BoxId}}">
            <button type="submit">{{name}}</button>
        </form>
  {{/each}}
```

Essentially on that page I am trying to run a for loop, where a new button form must be generated with each item found in the database. If there 5 items with name, and box value, then this should produce 5 times with their respective value and name set.

However, this is a secondary problem, because even doing `<h3> {{name}} </h3>` it doesnt work and i get the set headers problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
Template language being used:
http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Are you getting rows in a callback then rendering the template?

Comment: I doubt that the error is being caused _just_ by calling `res.render()`. There's probably some other code in your route handler, or possibly the middleware stack, that is already sending a response. Can you show a bit more context? Like how `rows` is being retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have this setup, but is the res.render itself in a for loop? If so, pass the entire data set to the template, and loop through in the template itself, something like:

```
var data = {
 rows: rows
}
res.render('information', data);
```

And in the template:

```
{{#each rows}}
   {{this.propName}}
{{/each}}
```

If you have nested data, you can have nested {{#each}} statements as well.